# Present Perfect or Past Simple?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Which one is correct?

1. Where did you put my dictionary? I can't find it.
2. Where have you put my dictionary? I can't find it.

Comment: One of these is probably a duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=present+perfect+past+simple

Comment: I would go with this [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23057/present-perfect-tense-vs-simple-past-tense) for the base for the duplicate. It has a great answer, courtesy @StoneyB, and some of those other questions have wonky contexts.

Comment: @δοῦλος I think you picked the best one. When I did the search I didn't expect to have so many to sort through and was short on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are correct.

Option #1 is more common.

Option #2 has a stronger implication that the dictionary should still be where "you put it".